# How to flag items with repeated names and with condition its value less than 20?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Problem
[image]

How to return "True" for the repeated items and with both values less than 20?

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1
```

I am able to detect repeated items, but not sure how to combine another condition.

Expected Results

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try this but it should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A1)*(B:B<20))>1
```

The function evaluates column one with condition one and column two with condition two. Then it multiplies both result vectors and sums the elements of the resulting vector.
If both conditions are met more than one time the function evaluates to `TRUE`, else to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

My data sample is like this:

[image]

And the formula I've used is:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;A2;$B$2:$B$7;"<"&20)=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;A2);COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7;A2)>1);TRUE;FALSE)
```

I've used COUNTIFS.

> **[COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

With COUNTIFS, I've counted how many cells share same letter and value <20, and I compare that count with counting how many cells share same letter only. If equal, it means all letters got value <20. Also, with the AND part, I've added a second condition, and it's checking if the count of cells with same letter is >1, to make sure this applies only to repeated values (X is 15, but not repeated, so it returns FALSE).

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND()` if you want to check multiple true/false statements.

`=AND( COUNTIF(A:A, A2)>1,  B2<20)`

[image]